# How to keep SSHD open when out of memory

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm on EC2 t2.small instance (2GB RAM) and keep getting locked outside the server without the ability to ssh into it.
error message is `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`
Knowing the application, I assume it leaks memory and that SSHD is blcoked due to that.

**Is there a way to allow SSH connection to a linux box that has its RAM full?**
Can I someone have SSHD reserve enough memory for new connections?

Comment: "I assume" - don't assume. Read your logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can't pre-allocate memory for `sshd`, you can set the memory limit for the application in such a way that it can't eat all the memory. See `man ulimit` how to do that.

If it's a Java application, try `-Xmx` to set the maximum amount of memory which it can allocate.

Answer (score 9):

When server runs into out-of-memory, it usually kills several applications which is control by OOM(out of memory) Killer. In your case when your server goes into out-of-memory it kills SSH process to free ram. We can avoid this by disabling OOM killer for ssh Process :

Disabling OOM killer for any process :

```
  echo -17 > /proc/`pidof Process`/oom_adj
```

Disabling OOM Killer for ssh all process:

```
 pgrep -f "/usr/sbin/sshd" | while read PID; do echo -17 > /proc/$PID/oom_adj; done
```

To automate this we need to set crontab for 1 min

```
   */1 * * * * root pgrep -f "/usr/sbin/sshd" | while read PID; do echo -17 > /proc/$PID/oom_adj; done
```

You can read more about the Linux OOM killer [here](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer).

Comment: A simpler explanation for what the OP experienced is that `sshd` couldn't fork because of the out-of-memory condition.

Comment: You don't fix OOM issues by whitelisting applications.

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to issue above commands but each time I get 'permission denied', even when issued with sudo. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

When a user space process makes the system to run out of virtual memory, there's no process killing in the kernel.  Normally running out of memory translates in some process trying to grow and being unable to do so, due to lack of memory resources (**malloc(3)** fails on **sbrk(2)**)

Normally, all programs are more or less designed to cope someway with these kind of errors, but normally (as memory is essential for them to run) they resolve to terminate in some way or another.  This happens to **sshd(8)** also.

The expensive way to solve for this problem is to *add physicall ram to your system*, but if you don't want to do this, there's another method, less expensive, but somewhat daunting: is to *add swap space to your system*.  Remember, virtual memory is composed of real, physicall memory and virtual, non-real, secondary storage memory.  Add swap to your system, at least to test if this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, would be to allocate some ZRAM.

It would help, if you don't use a SWAP file (due to disk limitations), and have very limited RAM.

ZRAM comes at some computational cost, as memory items need to be compressed/decompressed each time they're written/read from RAM.

But it's entirely possible to add 300 to 500MB of RAM just through RAM compression.
It may be enough to host your GUI and other background process data.